# Input validation while using streams

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I figured out how to use streams-lambdas instead of for loop
(just started with streams and lambdas)

this is the previous method i had

```java
public void findVehicle(){
        System.out.println("Input a vehicle rego: ");
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String rego = in.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<vehicles.size();i++){
            if (vehicles.get(i).getRego().equals(rego)){
                System.out.println(vehicles.get(i).toString());
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The vehicle does not exist.");
    }
```

and this is my method now

```java
public void findVehicle(){
        System.out.println("Input a vehicle rego: ");
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String rego = in.nextLine();


           vehicles.stream()
                    .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getRego().equals(rego.toUpperCase()))
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

this stream works perfectly but i want it to return once found and printed the vehicle and if vehicle not found the method continues and prints the error statement.
Thanks!

Comment: Streams are not the be-all and end-all in Java.  This is one of those times where streams are not useful.

Comment: @JimGarrison check the other answer from 英語は苦手 works like a charm... but i get what you are saying .. i would rather stick to my for loops for now but just trynna use where ever i can and see what i get to learn

Comment: the only thing i can see it didn't cover was i didn't use ```rego.toUpperCase()``` with forloop and forloop will only work for one match not all unless i use a boolean inside.. is there anything else I'm missing ?

Comment: Yes, you can accomplish this with streams... but consider which one is more readable and maintainable.  This "shiny new object" syndrome is epitomized by this quote from a different context: _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  _Now they have two problems."_  -- [Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
vehicles.stream()
    .filter(v -> v.getRego().equals(rego.toUpperCase()))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        System.out::println,
        () -> System.out.println("The vehicle does not exist."));
```